# Why workers in work manager still in ENQUEUED state?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm creating OneTimeWorkRequest with NetworkType.CONNECTED constraint, but even though the device is connected to the internet, the request is still in ENQUEUED state

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();

OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();

WorkContinuation continuation = mWorkManager.beginUniqueWork("work",
                    ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);

continuation.enqueue();
```

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Comment: Is your SyncWorker an inner class? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515760/18202

Comment: Did you find any solution? Some of my users are currently facing the same issues with some of their china phones like Tecno

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();

OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Have you debugged into your worker class to see if it is being executed? Is it possible it's not succeeding and therefore retrying itself?

Comment: facing the same issue with the beta03 release of the library. Worker used to be triggered but since yesterday its not triggered at all and stays in enqueued state. I've set the same network constraint as above and time of 15 minutes. But its a periodic request in my case.