# Android Work Manager: "Could not instantiate Worker"

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

I've followed the [Android Developer's](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#workflow) tutorial on using the Worker Manager structure to run my code in background but anytime I try to enqueue my worker it doesn't run and I get the following error:

```
2018-10-04 22:25:47.004 28669-28885/app.package.com.debug E/DefaultWorkerFactory: Could not instantiate app.package.com.MyWorker
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2320)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2166)
        at androidx.work.DefaultWorkerFactory.createWorker(DefaultWorkerFactory.java:58)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:180)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2018-10-04 22:25:47.005 28669-28885/app.package.com.debug E/WorkerWrapper: Could for create Worker app.package.com.MyWorker
```

I've seen that this problem could be related to the default constructor on the worker but I already use the correct one instead of the deprecated default function.

My worker is declared as:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        // Doesn't even get called
    }
}
```

And it gets queued like so:

```
WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
if (myWorkerRequest == null) {
    myWorkerRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
            .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .build())
            .build();
}
WorkStatus workStatus = workManager.getStatusById(myWorkerRequest.getId()).getValue();
if (workStatus == null || !workStatus.getState().isFinished()) {
    workManager.enqueue(myWorkerRequest);
}
```

I'm not seeing anything different from the examples so I'd like to understand what else could affect my code to cause this crash. Could it be something ProGuard related?

My version is `1.0.0-alpha09`

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116296569) with WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha09 that is already marked as fixed for alpha10.

As a workaround, you can add the following lines to your proguard configuration:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends androidx.work.Worker {
    public <init>(android.content.Context,androidx.work.WorkerParameters);
}
```

Comment: @ianhanniballake So... You need to add proguard restriction even if you don't use it ?

Comment: I have been facing the same issue with 1.0.0-beta01 and it seems that my constructor (of my custom worker) has been package-private. For workmanager to work it needs to be public. I made the constructor public and it works like a charm.

Comment: In my case i have made class as default modifier , i made it to public and it worked.

Comment: still got this exception on android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1 (Android Emulator 9.0). have you upgrade to 1.0.1? @ianhanniballake

Comment: same exception  in 2.2.0

Comment: Didn't work for me (using Hilt and RxWorker): I had to downgrade from 2.6.0-alpha02 to 2.5.0.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue. The cause of the issue for me was that my Worker class was a nested class. The moment I made it an independent class, it worked.

Comment: That solved my issue as well. Adding a proguard exclusion didn't.

Comment: thx, saved my day!  independent class only! But what's the diff?

Answer (score 15):

If you are using on-demand initialization and Dagger to inject the whole configuration, make sure to remove WorkManager default initialization by adding the following provider in AndroidManifest, as suggested by the [pull request](https://github.com/google/iosched/commit/886ef3b7c483760478406dde76fe637fccfd13a9). This was the only thing which helped me. For more details, check the [blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/customizing-workmanager-with-dagger-1029688c0978).

```
<!-- Remove WorkManager default initialization -->
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: Very helpful. More explanation can be found from the official docs https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration

Comment: I upgraded to 2.6 which the default initialization removed by different way, that was the problem to me

Answer (score 12):

The problem for me was the constructor of my kotlin class:

WRONG

```
class MyWorker(val app: Application, workerParams: WorkerParameters): Worker(app, workerParams)
```

GOOD

```
class MyWorker(val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): Worker(context, workerParams)
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer. Deep inside the WorkManager code, there's an implementation of WorkerFactory interface, which creates a Worker based on a context && workerParams.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem in stable version 1.0.0 and I fixed it by making my worker class public.

```
class MyWorker extends Worker {...} > public class MyWorker extends Worker {...}
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue and my solution is here

1. I update work manager version **"2.6.0-alpha02"** previous version was "2.5.0"
2. You need to add provider with meta-data into the manifest.

```html
    <provider
      android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
      android:exported="false"
      tools:node="merge">
      <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>
```

3. You need to inject HiltWorkerFactory to Application class and setWorkerFactory

```html
@HiltAndroidApp
class App: Application(), Configuration.Provider {

@Inject
lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [Tony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515760/5701177):

Another thing to keep in mind if you're using Kotlin is that the Worker class *can* be nested, but it **cannot be marked as `inner`**.

I suspect that if you're using Java, you might also be able to use a nested class if you mark it as `static`. But I haven't tested this.

Comment: Add `static` was the solution for me in Java. 
I only needed to store the `context` in `Worker` constructor to reuse it in `doWork()`.

Comment: Yeah this answer works for nested worker classes. Thanks. Also ended up doing the same as Salvador and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `Worker` with `Hilt`, then, in addition to all [other](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) [requirements](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration), make sure you are [also adding](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager) `HiltWorkerFactory` to your `Application` class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App: Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error then i realized to add app start up library which resolved my issue

manifest file

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge">
        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>
```

build.gradle.app

```
 def work_version = "2.6.0"
    // Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37"

    //app start up
    implementation("androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.0")
```

i just added app startup library and set up in Android menifest

Answer (score 1):

I've added this `kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"` dependency in the app.gradle and error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found another case where you might run into `NoSuchMethodException`

If you have these gradle properties enabled:

```
kapt.classloaders.cache.size=6

kapt.include.compile.classpath=false
```

this does aggressive caching of KAPT which results in WorkManager not initialized by `hilt`

I removed these properties and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This issue came to me when i copy pasted Worker class to create new Worker class

Solution

Clean Project and Running app solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading from OneSignal 4.8.5+ to 4.8.4.

Just in case you tried all the above solutions and are still having problems with Hilt Workers. OneSignal 4.8.5 introduced a bug that initialized the WorkManager before hilt could do so. I noticed it because in my application class getWorkManagerConfiguration() was never called. Downgrading to OneSignal 4.8.4. It took me a couple days to figure this out.

There is a bug filed here:
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/1748

Answer (score 0):

As I had to update

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.5.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
```

and `WorkManagerInitializer` wasn't available in the last version
the following change in `AndroidManifest.xml` resolved the issue:

Before:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

After:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

The solution with `"merge"` suggested by others still caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in build.gradle

```
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.49")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.49")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.1.0")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.49")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.1.0")
    implementation ("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$workManagerVersion")
    implementation ("androidx.work:work-runtime:$workManagerVersion")
```

Add below code in Manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge">
        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>
```

Your Application class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory
    override val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration
        get() = Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
    
}
```

And Your Worker class

```
@HiltWorker
class ImageFormUpload @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context, @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
    private val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder,
    private val notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ImageFormUpload"
    }

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
       Log.d(TAG, "doWork: Worked thread")

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```