# Android Worker class as nested class

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using WorkManager in my app. I get the “Could not instantiate Worker” error when my worker class is a nested class (inside my activity).
As discussed in the link below, the solution that worked for me is to make my worker an independent class.

[Android Work Manager: "Could not instantiate Worker"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657196/android-work-manager-could-not-instantiate-worker).

Is there a way to make my worker a nested class?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro no.. let me know if you find

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior with WorkManager's default `WorkerFactory` because it uses reflection to find the Worker class. For this reason it needs to be public and not an inner class.

What is the use case to use an inner class for your Worker?
If you need to pass some additional parameters to your Worker you can define a custom WorkerFactory and pass the additional parameters there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using kotlin, then you can remove the "[inner](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html)" keyword from your class declaration. This should get rid of the error. However, you'll lose the ability to access the members of its outer class.

Comment: I''m using java, and the whole point for me is to have access to the outer class members.