# Workers cannot be instantiated with NoSuchMethodException in minified variant

Tags: android, proguard, dagger-2, android-workmanager

I am using Android's WorkManager for background tasks and everything works great until I am trying to use it in a minified build. When the service should be initialized I am getting the following exception:

```
Could not instantiate *REDACTED*Worker
                                                                                                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: *REDACTED*Worker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2328)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2167)
                                                                                                        at e1.y.b(SourceFile:65)
                                                                                                        at f1.j.k(SourceFile:358)
                                                                                                        at f1.j.run(SourceFile:17)
                                                                                                        at n1.i$a.run(SourceFile:3)
```

- I have followed the required steps for [Custom WorkManager Configuration and Initialization](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/configuration/custom-configuration), but still getting this issue for minified build.
- I am using Dagger2 (not Hilt) and RxWorker
- I am providing a custom WorkerFactory implementation.
- Gradle:

```
...
// workVersion is 2.7.1
implementation "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:$workVersion"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$workVersion"
```

- Manifest:

```
<application
>
 ...
 <provider
      android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
      android:exported="false"
      tools:node="remove" />
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657196/android-work-manager-could-not-instantiate-worker) which refers to older version and suggests to add the following to the proguard file:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends androidx.work.Worker {
    public <init>(android.content.Context,androidx.work.WorkerParameters);
}
```

But that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: WorkManager [already has that ProGuard rule](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:work/work-runtime/proguard-rules.pro;l=3), so there's nothing you need to do ProGuard wise. If you are using a custom WorkerFactory, then you wouldn't be constructing the Worker via reflection into the constructor (right?), which is exactly what the error message says you are doing. What are the obfuscated `e1.y.b`, `f1.j.k`, etc. from the stack trace?

Comment: @ianhanniballake That's correct, I am not using reflection for constructing the Workers. I looked at the mapping (unfortunately the issue doesn't reproduce with `debuggable true`) and this is what i found:
`androidx.work.WorkerFactory -> e1.y:`
`createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(android.content.Context,java.lang.String,androidx.work.WorkerParameters):83:83 -> b` (repeats multiple times)
`androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper -> f1.j:`
`androidx.work.ListenableWorker mWorker -> k`
`androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task -> n1.i$a:`

To my understanding, the custom factory is not called.

Comment: Then it seems you know where to look at - where you install and configure your custom factory. You'd have to include that code here to have us help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging this issue I found out that my custom factory was invoked, but it threw an exception that I caught inside a try-catch block (thus I didn't see it in the logs) and returned `null`. When the custom factory returns null, it [falls back to use reflection](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:work/work-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/work/WorkerFactory.java;l=82?q=createWorkerWithDefaultFallback).

Comment: i don't understand, could you share working code? i have same issue